# SQL Server - XML parsing returning NULL

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

Struggling with parsing data from `xml` generated by third party. Checked if there are no issues with `XML` structure, and already parse dozens of similar structure `XMLs` without any issue.

`XML` got this structure:

```
 <rss xmlns:media="https://...." version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link>Link</link>
    <description>description</description>
    <pubDate>01.01.1900</pubDate>
    <item>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">aaaa</guid>
      <title>Title</title>
      <description>description</description>
      <pubDate>pubDate</pubDate>
      <category>Category</category>
      <enclosure url="https:..." length="72" type="video/mp4" />
      <media:content type="video/mp4" url="https://..." duration="72" lang="en">
        <media:category>AAAA</media:category>
        <media:tags>BBB</media:tags>
        <media:keywords>CCCC</media:keywords>
        <media:thumbnail url="https://...." width="1280" height="720" />
        <media:credit role="producer" scheme="urn:ebu">DDDD</media:credit>
      </media:content>
    </item>
```

I`m unable to parse anything which is under` media:content`. Where full path to it should be` /rss/channel/item/media:content/media:thumbnail`, but apparently is not.

Probably missing something oblivious.

Would massively appreciate if someone could advise me on that, and best regards all Happy New Year !!! :)

Comment: *"I`m unable to parse anything which is under "media:content"."* Because you don't declare the namespace.

Comment: I did:;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' as "media")
 select 
 x.y.value('media:content[1]/media:thumbnail[1]/@url', 'nvarchar(max)') as [Thubmnail]
 FROM @xml.nodes('/rss/channel/item') AS x(y)
Sorry forgot to add

Comment: `FROM @xml.nodes('/media:rss/channel/item')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mention in the comment, you need to declare your namespace in the SQL:

```sql
DECLARE @XML xml = '<rss xmlns:media="https://...." version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link>Link</link>
    <description>description</description>
    <pubDate>01.01.1900</pubDate>
    <item>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">aaaa</guid>
      <title>Title</title>
      <description>description</description>
      <pubDate>pubDate</pubDate>
      <category>Category</category>
      <enclosure url="https:..." length="72" type="video/mp4" />
      <media:content type="video/mp4" url="https://..." duration="72" lang="en">
        <media:category>AAAA</media:category>
        <media:tags>BBB</media:tags>
        <media:keywords>CCCC</media:keywords>
        <media:thumbnail url="https://...." width="1280" height="720" />
        <media:credit role="producer" scheme="urn:ebu">DDDD</media:credit>
      </media:content>
    </item>
  </channel>' + --Assumed exists
'</rss>'; --Assumed exists

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('https://....' as media) --'https://....' would be replaced with your real namespace
SELECT c.i.value('media:content[1]/media:thumbnail[1]/@url', 'nvarchar(max)') as [Thubmnail]
FROM @xml.nodes('/rss/channel/item') AS c(i);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8a8a1e1ef713a7c3285ed3a6e0f53a27)

Comment: Thank you Larnu, thx to you i`ve found my issue was the http against https in NS.
Of course you couldn`t know that as i haven`t put real values.. But you point me where to look for it. 
Massive thx again and Happy New Year Sir !!! :)